# Python: expected an indented block error

Tags: python

when I ran my program of a blackjack game, the python idle 3.4.2 came up with an error message saying, "Expected an indented block".

```
def end(player):
    if player == 1:
        print('You win, well done')
    elif player == 0:
        print('Computer won, game over')
    print("Computer's cards:")
    deal(computer_suit1,computer_card1)
    deal(computer_suit2,computer_card2)
    startup()
```

Comment: Mixed tabs and spaces probably

Comment: Check if your indentation fits what is shown here and if you have mixed tabs and spaces!

Comment: I believe this error should also specify a line number.

Comment: Please include the entire error message.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  In this case, your posted code doesn't reproduce the problem, and you failed to include the entire error message, so we can't tell where you have the problem.  That said, the space/tab mixture is a likely candidate.